# Compilation problem in Geany

Tags: compiling, ide

I started using Geany recently and I tried to compile a new .c file I wrote, but the complier did not seem to recognize conio.h ["Fatal Error"] and simply ignored math.h. As a result I could not build the program. I have never faced this problem before. Do I have to download and save all the headers in the project directory? Please help.

Comment: What are you trying to compile? as far as I know, `conio.h` is essentially a Windows header file. Also what exactly do you mean by math.h being "simply ignored"? can you post the actual output text that you see in the geany build pane?

Comment: I realized that I need to use gcc -lmath <filename> in order to compile math.h functions. 

gcc -lm Diodecurrents.c;

However, I am still getting the following error:
Diodecurrents.c:4:6: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘-’ token

Wonder what is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Geany doesn't have nothing to do with this. I'm sure that you will get the same errors if you are compiling your program from terminal. This because `conio.h` is specific to the Windows environment. Use `ncurses.h` library on Unix like systems; its functions are similar to ones in `conio.h`.

See http://tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know that. I always thought the headers would irrespective of the environment. However, despite replacing conio.h with ncurses.h, I got similar errors. 

http://i41.tinypic.com/epglci.png
http://i44.tinypic.com/2zsd5i9.png

Wonder why this is happening?

Comment: @UserName Yes, of course, you didn't checked the link that I gave you. `ncurses` need to be installed first: http://tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/intro.html#WHERETOGETIT .